# Django form not being submitted

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have a Django model/view/form that is rendering correctly in the template, but it is not submitting the data that is input to the database.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserRegistration(models.Model):
    user_first = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_last = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_email = models.EmailField()
    #user_fantasyhost = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.user_first, self.user_last, self.user_email)

class RegForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRegistration

#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
from acme.dc_django.models import UserRegistration
from acme.dc_django.models import RegForm

def regPage(request, id=None):
    form = RegForm(request.POST or None,
                       instance=id and UserRegistration.objects.get(id=id))

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/league_setup/')
    user_info = UserRegistration.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'user_info' :user_info,
    }

    return render(request, 'regpage.html', context)

#repage.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<head>
    <title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="/league/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>{{ form }}</table>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account" 
    </form><br /><br />

</body>
</HTML>
```

Thank you for your help,

dp

Comment: You haven't closed your form submit tag, but that might just be a typo, and your browser can probably handle it. This kind of problem is often easier for you to debug than us. Where is the view going wrong? Put some print statements in the view to find out. What, for example, is the value of `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: could you please elaborate what is not working? i find `but it is not submitting the data that is input to the database` confusing

Comment: I am not getting errors, when I get back to my desktop I will include print statements. The problem is that when I click on the submit button nothing happens--nothing at all.  Now that you point out the open tag, I will see if that is a typo or if that is the problem. More later. Thank you.

Comment: I closed the submit tag and the submit button now takes me to the correct page, but the data is never written to the database, I will insert the print statements...

Comment: update the code samples please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried your code. Your problem is that the **action** attribute of your html **form tag** is set to "/league/".

**Unless reqPage url is actually "/league/", it won't work**. When i changed `action="/league/"` to `action=""` as such:

```
<HTML lang="en">
<head>
    <title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <table>{{ form }}</table>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account"  />
    </form><br /><br />

</body>
</HTML>
```

The form **did** work:

```
In [3]: UserRegistration.objects.all()
Out[3]: [<UserRegistration: aoeu oeu oeu@aeou.com>]
```

Comment: before I saw your answer, I did the same thing and got the same result! Thank you for your help!  dp